# Is it bad to edit a question later, when you realized you were confused/unclear to yourself what you wanted to ask?

Tags: discussion

There was an answer on this question but user removed it for some reasons (asking too many questions in comments and finally changing the question significantly).

I didn't find anything wrong in the answer. Almost all doubts were cleared but 1 or 2 doubts were still pending in my mind. That's when things went bad.

I understand when someone makes a lot of effort and spends time on composing an answer, it obviously is *bad* to edit question significantly.

But if you see my side, I also did research before asking question. It wasn't just another *simple* question. Added sufficient details. And when I realized the question wasn't specific *(it still might not be on topic or rude or bad)*, I edited it make it more specific.

But when the user said that it's considered bad form, comments, it made me wonder I made a mistake by editing that question. And hence my response to *defend* myself from that user was indeed rude.

**So did I do bad by editing this question here? Should I had asked a new question instead?**

[Are these both ways okay to lower the flame in these types of gas stoves?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115102/are-these-both-ways-okay-to-lower-the-flame-in-these-types-of-gas-stoves?noredirect=1#comment185073_115102)